# Accesing user control on masterpage from content

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to access a user control, that is stored on the master page, from my content pages.
So far I've tried using `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="" TypeName=""%>` on my content pages, but I can't seem to get it work.

Masterpage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="My" TagName="RightPanel" Src="~/RightPanel.ascx" %>
<My:RightPanel runat="server" ID="RightPanel"/>
```

Content page (frontend)

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" TypeName="RightPanel"%>
```

But I can't call the RightPanel from my codebehind.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:**Master.FindControl**

```
RightPanel u = Master.FindControl("RightPanel") as RightPanel;
```